# match part of string in R

Tags: string, r, substring

I'm stuck with something that usually is pretty easily in other programming languages.

I want to test whether a string is inside another one in R. For example I tried:

```
match("Diagnosi Prenatale,Esercizio Fisico", "Diagnosi Prenatale")
pmatch("Diagnosi Prenatale,Esercizio Fisico", "Diagnosi Prenatale")
grep("Diagnosi Prenatale,Esercizio Fisico", "Diagnosi Prenatale")
```

And none worked. To make it work I should fist split the first string with strsplit and extract the first element.

NOTE: I'd like to do this on a vector of strings to receive a yes/no vector, so in the function I wrote should go a vector not a single string. But of course if the single string doesn't work, image a full vector of them...

Any ideas?

Comment: Some quick notes: (1) you wouldn't use `match` or `pmatch` for this task - these are for matching in a list. (2) you're using `grep` incorrectly - the pattern is the first argument and the text is the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `grepl`

```
grepl("Diagnosi Prenatale","Diagnosi Prenatale,Esercizio Fisico" )
[1] TRUE
```

You can also do this with character vectors, for example:

```
x <- c("Diagnosi Prenatale,Esercizio Fisico", "Diagnosi Prenatale")
grepl("Diagnosi Prenatale",x)
#[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Good answer. I would note that the OP used `grep` incorrectly which is why his code didn't work. I'm often throw off by the fact that pattern is the first argument.